# How to replace whitespace in jquery to pass to php?

Tags: php, jquery, get

I'm trying to make some auto suggest stuff for an app. But i'm having some problems. I wrote this jquery code to detect when there is a change in the input:

```
   function soletsgo(){
        $('#theinput').keyup(function(){
          value = $('#theinput').val();
          if ( value.length > 2 ){
            word = $('#theinput').val();
            word.replace(/\s/g, "&nbsp");
            $("#autodatathing").load("../pages/searchy.php?word="+word+"");
        } else {

        }  });  }
```

And there is a PHP file (searchy.php) that processes some stuff:

```
<?php
$now = htmlentities($_GET['word']);

echo "<p>";
echo $now;
echo "</p>";
?>
```

But, when i put in a 'space' (known as 'whitespace') in the 'input', there is no result!
Could someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do `escape(word)` in javascript code, then `rawurldecode($_GET['word'])` in php. Also if you have issues with utf8 encoding (i had in my past experience) you might consider using [this function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php#79595) instead of rawurldecode.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```
function soletsgo(){
        $('#theinput').keyup(function(){
          value = $('#theinput').val();
          if ( value.length > 2 ){
            word = $('#theinput').val();
            word.replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
            $("#autodatathing").load("../pages/searchy.php?word="+word+"");
          } else {

          }  
        });
}
```

You could also do it on the server side using:

```
<?php
  $now = str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", htmlentities($_GET['word']));

  echo "<p>";
  echo $now;
  echo "</p>";
?>
```